# Sending search parameter from activity to google maps api (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

First of, just gonna say that i'm not the best at explaining (nor at programming), so bear with me.

**The layout:**

I have two activities.
First one is the main activity where a checkbox and a button are located.
the second activity is the google maps api.

**The progress:**

When I click the button I enter the google maps activity (using intent) and have a fixed location.

**The problem:**

I want to send a location search to google maps IF the checkbox is checked when pressing the button (*example: if the checkbox says bowling, the search would be for bowling*), but I don't know how nor where to write this code.

Any links/tips/answers are appreciated :)

**MainActivity**

```
private static Button button_Ok;
private static CheckBox bowling;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    onClickButtonListener();
}

public void onClickButtonListener() {
    button_Ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    bowling = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    button_Ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**MapsActivity**

```
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = *fixed*; //myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = *fixed*; //myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));

    LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoordinates, 12);
    mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(myCoordinates)      // Sets the center of the map to LatLng (refer to previous snippet)
            .zoom(13)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(0)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    // ... get a map.
    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(*fixed*, *fixed*))
            .radius(100)
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT));


    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}

}
```

I've set fixed LatLng because the get location function doesn't seem to work on the emulator.

Comment: Please post you code.

Comment: You question is too general. Here is a tutorial that solves your problem: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: @RajanBhavsar Sorry about that, it said to try and keep it general :) thanks for the tutorial, i'll give it a read:) however i don't want the user to write searches, the point is to have them choose one of the checkboxes :) Again, sorry and thanks for the help, i'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the code you would use as there are about a dozen different ways to do this but I could suggest how I would implement this functionality.

I would have one activity `MapActivity` and two fragments.  One fragment containing the checkbox and search button (`buttonFragment`) and the second fragment would show your Google Maps (`mapFragment`).  Doing it this way, you only have to initialize and set up GoogleMaps once and can access the API's functionality from buttonFragment.

On your button press you would use GoogleMaps to get your Location, using the Google Places API you can return a list of nearby places, you would then pass this information to your activity using an interface callback, which would then launch the mapFragment and pass the information received from buttonFragment.

Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/

Google Places API:
https://developers.google.com/places/

Comment: Since i'm new to this scene I don't really know how to go about things :) I will look into the fragments way of solving it, since it seems to be on the right path :) Thank you for the help!